# Python can not read directory

Tags: python, pyopengl

So, i have a folder with my shader code, in my main python script (outside of the shader folder) i have a line of code :

```py
self.shader = self.createShader("shaders/vertex.txt", "shaders/fragment.txt")
```

but it just spits out this error

> ```py
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'shaders/vertex.txt'
> ```

Comment: what does `import os; print(os.getcwd())` say? put the line before `self.shader = ...`

Comment: It may be that the running current working directory is not what you think it is. Try adding a `print(os.getcwd())` just before that line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to put the files in the same directory or sub directory. You also need to set the working directory.
The shader file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python script.
The name and relative path of the python file can be retrieved with [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). So the absolute path to the python script is `os.path.abspath(__file__))`. The current working directory can be changed with [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Copy the following at the beginning of your code to set the working directory to the same as the script's directory:

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```